# can i update the same primary key to remote database with SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am able to update record to remote with sqlbulk copy for a table with no primary key.
can i use the same for primary key tables?

```
 public bool PublishMealDealDetail()
        {
            bool isUpdated = true;
            try
            {
                DataTable dtLocal = libEPOS.cMealDeal.GetAllMealDealDetailsDTForExport();
                if (dtLocal.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //truncate table on web
                    string sqlTrunc = "TRUNCATE TABLE MealDealDetail";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlTrunc, connWeb, transaction);
                    // connWeb.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connWeb);
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "MealDealDetail";
                    try
                    {
                        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtLocal);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        isUpdated = false;
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                isUpdated = false;
                throw ex;
            }

            return isUpdated;
        }
```

Comment: No bulkCopy do not copy the value for primary key, it changes it.

Comment: Did u tried my suggest answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can make use of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` to keep identity from one source to other source while updating tables.

MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(connWeb,System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);
```